# Using a division algorithm show that: $6|n(n+1)(n+2)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Using the division algorithm show that for any positive integer n,

$$6|n(n+1)(n+2)$$

I have some work on this but I do not think I'm taking the right path! Please advise! Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What exactly is the *division algorithm* you are referring too?

Comment: For ints a,b > 0, there are unique integers q(quotient) and r(remainder) satisfying a=bq+r where 0<=r<b. (I apologize I do not have less than or equal to sign on my phone)

Comment: That isn't an algorithm at all.

Comment: Your title is missing a factor $n$ and is not true.  It is correct in the body.  Please click the edit button below your question and fix it.

Comment: It is the algorithm that I am working with from my professor.

Comment: $$\binom{n+2}{3}\in\mathbb{Z}$$

Comment: Is $n$ natural number?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not sure how you would show it using any division algorithm, but $n(n+1)(n+2)$ is the product of three consecutive integers. So can you show that $2$ must divide one of those integers? Can you show that $3$ must divide one of those integers? If you can, then you've shown that $6$ must divide their product.